# Basic CRUD failing on new contract

Tags: server, postman, crud, firewall

so I got my first paid job after just getting out of a bootcamp. It's frankly a miracle. I really need to get this right.

About the project:

For development, I am using the client's server. There's a mySQL db there, and eventually I'm going to have a mobile app that does crud off of the server, before deploying this for a 3rd party. The problem is that I can't even make a successful request with Postman.

I wrote a node.js file with a single endpoint. I ran it on the server via remote desktop, and confirmed it was running with console logs. The ip address is right, as is the port (the client confirmed the port is open).

However, when running a get request with postman, it times out. I'm thinking it could be the firewall blocking my computer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

assuming a few things:

- you can connect to that same server ip via vnc port
- the nodejs server is listening to 0.0.0.0 or via a reachable IP address other than 127.0.0.1/localhost (ie, you can ping the server address)

then yes, it's a firewall problem. You can try to use a higher port and play with `netcat -vvv -l -p <new port>` to see if you can connect to a new ip/port via postman

please post the logs and nodejs code.